# Log MySQL general log to file slow query log to table

Tags: mysql, logging

I would like to log my slow queries to a table, but keep my general log(?) logged in a table. I assume the general log is my binary log?  MySQL docs are less than clear on this stuff. My MySQL server is setup as a replication master and these are the relevant logging stanzas from my.cnf.

```
# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days               = 3
max_binlog_size                = 1000M
sync_binlog                    = 1

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time                = 2
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 0
```

I'm afriad if I add something like this:

```
log_output = TABLE
general-log
expire_logs_days = 1
```

it will affect my binlog or start logging everything that's already written to my binlog to a table, which I don't want. I'm essentially just looking to have slow queries (a day or two's worth maybe) written to a table rather than a file, without affecting any of my other current logging.

I'm using Server version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1-log (Ubuntu)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The setting `log_output` doesn't affect the binary log. It affects the general query log and the slow query log.

Comment: What is the general log? I don't have any reference to it in my current logging config and I don't want to start logging anything else. So I can just add log_output = TABLE and be done with it?